# Possible to click the "More" button in the zoom app participants view via applescript?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

In the Zoom app Participants view, is it possible to click the "More" button and then select "Clear All Feedback"?

[image]

[image]

For interactive sessions and training delivery the usage of reactions to get feedback from the audience is quite popular, for which the host needs then to frequently clear them. Unfortunately, there is [no shortcut for this action yet (but requested)](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/clear-all-feedback-keyboard-shortcut/45491) and neither a menu bar item but if we could trigger it with applescript then one could leave the participants pane open (I'm using a strean deck with physical buttons that can trigger/execute applescript).

FYI - I tried if there is any way to navigate via accessibility i.e. shift tab etc. but couldn't find anything out of the box working, just navigating up/down between participants, no way to click the button via keyboard.

Comment: I do not have or use **Zoom**, is it a standalone _application_ or it is it being done within a **Web Browser**? Either way, if there is no direct **AppleScript** method, then resorting to **UI Scripting** it probably can be done. You just need to determine the _hierarchical **UI element** structure_. This can be done with **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**, or by using **System Events** to query the interface, or by transcoding the **AppleScript** _code_ behind a recorded **Watch Me Do** _action_ in **Automator**.

Comment: I'm using the desktop app, it's one of the most popular online meeting apps. Thanks, I've seen the use of UI elements before somewhere, I think that may be the way to go as I can't install Xcode and Automator is a paid app. Any suggestion for an easy way to query the interface via System Events?

Comment: RE: "Automator is a paid app" --  **Automator** is not a paid _application_, it is a default _application_ installed as a part of the **macOS** install.

Comment: oh thanks, must have mixed it up with a similar app, haven't use it before. Which one could be faster and/or more reliable to execute? Or do you mean that using automator watch me do is giving em the applescript code I need? :)

Comment: If you open **Automator** and create a new _workflow_ and then click the **Record** _button_, then click the **Zoom** icon on the **Dock** then click the **More ⌄** button, then click **Clear All Feed Back** then stop the recording.  You can the select what's in the **Watch Me Do** _action_ that's automatically added to the _workflow_  and copy it and then paste it into **Script Editor**.  Then clean it up so it looks like the  _code_ as in any of my **AppleScript** answers. If you want, paste the _code_ to e.g. [https://paste.ee](https://paste.ee) and I'll clean it up for you.